# How to fix react error: Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...)

Tags: reactjs

am getting following error when i am upgrading react version to 0.13.*, how to fix this?

`Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's`render`method). Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.`

Comment: It looks like we'll need some additional context to be able to answer this properly. Do you have some specific code you can share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is present if you included ReactJS more than once. Check if there is no such thing as double import of React or whatever in your code (hard to tell without code). I had once such thing and I needed to manually add/remove componentns to find which is the bad one (and it had indeed, 2x ReactJS)

it also happened to me with ReactCSSTransitionGroup in ES6 with React 0.14.

Answer (score 0):

As Shiroo mentioned, it is because of react multi dependency issue, As i don't have control change other external dependency component. have fixed temporarily by removing all inner depended react modules(node_modules) @ build time. by writing grunt task.